# "PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target" using java.net HttpClient

Tags: java, ssl

I have a keystore file that is on my server and exported it into a .p12 file locally.

I'm using the java.net `HttpClient` class to make an HTTP GET request:

```
 HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

I set up my HttpClient as such:

```
httpClientBuilder = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
        .sslContext(sslContext)
        .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(500));
```

where sslContext is defined as:

```
    String keyStorePassword = "password";
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("pathToP12File.p12");
    keyStore.load(is, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

    KeyManagerFactory keyFactory =
        KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

    sslContext.init(keyManagers, null, null);
```

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about how `SSLContext` is set up such that the certification path isn't valid?

Comment: If the certificate is valid (i.e. the certificate is correctly verified in the browser), then maybe the intermediate certificates are missing in the certificate chain.

Answer (score 0):

`"PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"`

We get this error, when the client is unable to trust the server it is talking with. The reason for distrust is that the server certificate isn't issued by a globally trusted CA. Thus, you have to explicitly tell your HTTPClient to trust the CA that issued the certificate to this server.

First, we need to get the CA cert chain. If you don't have it already, you can get it by

1. Open the URL in chrome
2. Chrome will say "This site can’t provide a secure connection".
3. Click on the "Not Secure" option on the left of search bar.
4. Click "Certificate is not valid".
5. In the details tab, click "Copy to File".

Next, you must load this certificate to your HTTPClient. To do that

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path_to_the_saved_file);
CertificateFactory certFact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate) certFact.generateCertificate(new BufferedInputStream(fis));

KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
trustStore.load(null, null);
trustStore.setCertificateEntry("any_alias", ca);

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(trustStore);
TrustManager[] tm = tmf.getTrustManagers();

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagers, tm, null);
```